# #!/usr/bin/expect not working

Tags: scripting, shell-scripting, expect

This is probably an easy question, however have a simple expect script that I've add the executable bit to that seems to be ignoring the #!/usr/bin/expect  interpreter line. Further more, it also seems like variables are not being set since when I echo them they are blank...

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set device "1.1.1.1"
set user   "testuser"

spawn ssh $user@$device
echo $device
echo $user

ls -lh
-rwxr-xr-x  root  root    testexpect.exp
```

Thanks for your help community!!

P.S. I'm running Debian Wheezy, installed expect via apt-get install expect...thanks

Comment: What error (if any) are you getting?

Comment: spawn command not found

Comment: Please can you post post the full error ?

Comment: How are you running the script? Does it work as expected if you explicitly run it using expect (`expect -f textexpect.exp`)? Is the #! line the very first line of the file (that includes blank lines - the first two characters of file should be #!).

Comment: Also (not related to your immediate issue) `echo` isn't an `expect` command. You probably want `send_user`.

Comment: @Paul - actually, `echo` is valid in `expect`. It simply echoes the value passed to it to STDOUT.

Comment: @John - that's a `tcl` feature rather than `expect` and only applies to interactive shells not within scripts (at least by default). See http://wiki.tcl.tk/2541

Answer (score 1):

Expect is based on Tcl language, so you shouldn't use bash 'echo' - you should use 'puts' to print something on the screen:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set device "1.1.1.1"
set user   "testuser"
spawn ssh $user@$device
puts $device
puts $user
```

And you will got result like this:

```
$ ./test.exp
spawn ssh testuser@1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1
testuser
```

Answer (score 0):

The error messages suggests you are running the command with an explicit interpreter, eg:

```
bash ./testexpect.exp
```

This will ignore the "#!" line. Whatever is launching the script needs to just    name the file  (or explicitly say `expect ./testexpect.exp`).  If your #! line was bad you would have got `/usr/bin/expect: bad interpreter: ...`